# Equation to model and rate how good someone's focus is.

Tags: summation, mathematical-modeling

I am creating a rubric to measure how good my focus was during a study session. I find a simple 10/10 rating system is too inconsistent and can very from person to person. Right now I am modeling how physical and mental distractions would effect the sessions focus rating. Lets focus on mental distractions for now. I want to be able to take the number of times I get distracted and also weight the distractions based on how bad it was. I wish to use this to measure my ability to stay focused. for instance during a study session, I can have 2 distractions with a rating of 5/5 meaning they were really bad distractions and 3 distractions with a rating of 2/5 meaning they were somewhat bad distractions.

I dont want the number of distractions to linearly scale the rating. For instance 12 distractions should not be twice as bad as 6 distractions. It should be significantly worse. I was thinking of an exponential scale.  Similarly how bad the distraction is should also not linearly scale the rating. For instance, a 5/5 should be much worse than a 1/5.

Does anyone have a good model to form these ratings? I would like the final output to be out of 10.

One I idea I had was $R = 10 \cdot e^{-k \cdot \sum_{i} \left(Weight_i)^p \cdot Distraction_i^q\right)}
$, where R is the rating out of 10, k is the factor by which to scale how bad the distractions were. to measure how bad the distractions were, I have a weighted sum where the weights are between 0 and 1 where 1 is the absolute worst the distraction could be, and distraction is the number of times you got distracted by by a distraction with the weight i. The only issue is I'm not sure how good of a model this is and I'm not sure how to find the parameters.

I was also thinking of removing the exponential q.

This equation is meant to improve upon my [original rubric and equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyPWI.png)

any ideas recommendations or better ways to model and measure depth of focus would be greatly appreciated.